# Suppose $R$ and $S$ are relations. Define $R \cap S$ as $a(R \cap S)b \iff aRb$ and $aSb$

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Question asks is $R \cap S$ transitive given $R$ and $S$ are transitive. Not quite sure how to show this but I know it is definitely transitive.

I have a idea but don't know where to go with it if $R$ is transitive then,

$aRb$ and $bRc \implies aRc$

$aSb$ and $bSc \implies aSc$

Since $aRc$ and $aSc$ we conclude $a(R \cap S)c$ not sure if this is the right idea

Comment: This is the correct idea. What you are trying to show is $a(R\cap S)b \textrm{ and } b(R\cap S)c$ implies $a(R\cap S)c$, so you need to start with a supposition of the first statement.

Comment: So can I say since $aRb$ and $aSb$ we have that $a(R\cap S)b$ by definition and just do the same argument for $b$ and $c$

Comment: I think you have it backwards. If you want to prove $(R\cap S)$ is transitive, you start with $a(R\cap S)b$ and $b(R\cap S)c$ and try to show that taking these two statements as a starting point, we can get to $a(R\cap S)c$. So, you would start by saying that since $a(R \cap S)b$, $a R b$ and $a S b$, et cetera.

Comment: ahh ok I see where your getting at thanks!

Comment: Your title of the question and the body doesn't match completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a(R\cap S)b \land b(R\cap S)c \\\implies (a,b),(b,c)\in (R\cap S)\\\implies (a,b),(b,c)\in R \land (a,b),(b,c)\in S \\\implies (aRb \land bRc) \land(aSb \land bSc)\\\implies aRc \land aSc \\\implies a(R\cap S)c$